# Setting NODE_PATH from within NodeJS application

Tags: node.js

We have a node project that does not require our own submodules from a relative path, but instead needs the `NODE_PATH` environment variable be set to `lib` to find all submodules.

I wanted to handle this standard case within the program source code but it seems like it is impossible by now.

I found several solutions which all do not work as expected.

`module.paths.push("./lib");`

Was suggested in another stackoverflow article but this causes an error message in the newer Node versions and refers the developer to using `NODE_PATH`.

Instead I tried to do the following as the very first line of my program.

`process.env['NODE_PATH']="./lib";`

This does not cause an error message but it does not work either. I think that this variable is read on the application start and not read lateron when requiering stuff.

Comment: process.env['NODE_PATH']="./lib" replaces the content of NODE_PATH and does not add to it. Maybe that is your problem. if you use process.env['NODE_PATH']+=":./lib"  instead it should work

Comment: What I see is NODE_PATH programmatic setting works in worker processes if it was set inside master process. For master process itself it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 11):

All information you can find out from the source: [module.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js)

`... NODE_PATH` error is thrown only when accessing via `require.paths`.

Search for `_nodeModulePaths` function: Module instance has generic Array object `paths`, with all lookup paths in it.

```
module.paths.unshift('./foo-baz');
var x = require('some-lib-name');
console.log(x);
```

So now, if you have the required module under `./foo-baz/some-lib-name/` it would be properly picked up.

What node version and what system you have?